# laravel save method not saving data completely

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using Laravel to create a web bot that collects data from other websites and stores it in my MySQL database. When I want to save `body` I use `dd($this->render($post));` and it is good. Yet, when I use `$post->save()` for saving my post in db, it not saving the body of my post completely and some of text is missing.

My `body` is at least 10000 characters and I always have this problem.

I checked `text` and `longtext` for body column type and is not there any difference...

Where is problem?

edit :

this is my index method :

```
 public function getIndex()
    {
        $temp = App\Temp::where('status' , 0)->orderBy('id' , 'desc')->first();
        $temp->status = 1;
        $temp->save();
        $post = new App\Post;
        $post->title = $temp->title;
        $post->link = $temp->link;
        $post->desc = $temp->desc;
        $post->cat_id = $temp->cat_id;
        $post->url_id = $temp->url_id;
        $post->body = $this->render($post);
        $post->save();
        echo "+";
    }
```

When I am using `dd($this->render($post));` before save, it shows full text without any problem... but after save when I fetch the body, some characters is missing from the end of post...

and this is `render()` method...

```
public function render($post)
    {
        echo "Start : ";
        $this->ftp->createFolder('/'.$post->url_id.'/'.$post->id."/");
        echo "Dir - ";
        $mixed_body = $this->desc($post->title);
        echo "Mix - ";
        $body ="";
        $body = $body . '<h3><a href='.$this->postUrl.'>'.$this->postTitle.'</a></h3>';
        echo "Title - ";

        while(strlen($mixed_body) > 100)
        {
            $body = $body . $this->randImage($post);
            $body = $body . $this->randTitle();

            //insert a random paragraph
            $number = rand(100 , strlen($mixed_body));//temporary
            $paragraph = substr($mixed_body , 0 , $number);
            $mixed_body = substr($mixed_body , $number , strlen($mixed_body)-$number);

            $body = $body . '<p>' . $paragraph . '</p>';
            echo "P|";
        }
        echo "\nDone : ".strlen($body);
        return $body;
    }
```

others methods in `render()` are appending some text to `$body` and those are not important.

and my model :

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model {

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tag');
    }

}
```

Comment: does your model have a `$fillable` property and is the body attribute inside of it? [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: TEXT 65,535 bytes, LONGTEXT 4,294,967,295 bytes ~4GB... looks like a difference to me.... and note that is __byte__ size, not character size

Comment: Would you please post the rest of the code where the model is created/fetched and the column assignments are made, before you call the `save` method on it. The problem might lie there.

Comment: Forreal- post your code... like, did you ever assign the body to the post? $post->body = $body; $post->save();

Comment: @MikelBitson post edited...

Comment: What does $this->render do? Can you post that code too? If it's outputting with echo or print then you'd need to use output buffering to get it into a string.

Comment: @Bogdan When I check phpmyadmin , I see that post is not complete... and when fetching... too...

Comment: @MikelBitson code edited again.

Comment: Lol, ok, nothing major here- now can you show us the App\Post model code? Specifically the $fillable attribute.

Comment: @MikelBitson I do not have any $fillable attribute in my model... post edited :)

Comment: Alright- you really shouldn't need* a $fillable attribute for this, but try adding this to App\Post anyway:  protected $fillable = ['body'];

Comment: @watcher I do not have any $fillable attribute in my model... post edited

Comment: @MikelBitson It is not working yet

Comment: The fact that part of the body is saved proves there is no mass-assignment issue. Are you sure you have re-migrated your db after changing to longtext?

Comment: @jsphpl yes, I am sure. I checked it from phpmyadmin and that column type is longtext...

Comment: and is there still everything there when you dump `dd($post->body)` right **after** `$post->body = $this->render($post)` and **before** `$post->save()`?

Comment: @jsphpl exactly all things are there and is not any problem...

Comment: Have you considered escapes? Try to echo after the Data is escaped and see if the echoed result it's the same as in db

Comment: tnx @davejal... you helped me and I found the reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my problem reason...
sometimes I have a character like � in my body that laravel not saves the characters after it...
I find to use this line to delete � character...

$post->body = mb_convert_encoding($this->render($post), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');

thanks from all to help me, I have a very bad headache and want to rest...

thanks from all again, good night/morning/afternoon (according to your time-zones)  :)